# Trying to understand NSLayoutConstraints with swift

Tags: swift, nslayoutconstraint

I got a new book on how to make apps using swift, but it doesn't explain NSLayoutConstraints really well.  Here is an example code

```
let constraint = 
     NSLayoutConstraint(item: myLabel,
          attribute: NSLayoutConstraint.Attribute.centerX,
          relatedBy: NSLayoutConstraint.Relation.equal,
          toItem: myButton,
          attribute: NSLayoutConstraint.Attribute.centerX,
          multiplier: 1.0,
          constant: 0.0)
```

What I'm confused about is a few things, so thank you for taking the time to read this.

I see there are two attributes.  Is the first one an attribute of the text within the label and the second an attribute related to the button (myButton)?  I'm not really sure. Can you also explain the relatedBy portion.  Thanks.

Comment: Please read [Auto Layout Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/index.html) especially [Anatomy of a Constraint](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/AnatomyofaConstraint.html)

Answer (score 1):

Imagine this:

> Connect `<this object>` from `<this point>` to `<that point>` of `<that object>`, multiplied by `<1>` plus `<this much>` offset `<exactly/or more/or less>`.

I have tried to map this:

> Connect `<this object>`[1] from `<this point>`[2] to `<that point>`[5] of `<that object>`[4], multiplied by `<1>`[6] plus `<this much>`[7] offset `<exactly/or more/or less>`[3].

to the code explanation:

> Constraint `<myLabel>`[1] from `<.centerX>`[2] to `<.centerX>`[5] of `<myButton>`[4] multiplied by `<1.0>`[6] plus `<0.0>`[7] offset `<.equal/.greaterThanOrEqual/.lessThanOrEqual>`[3].

This was:

```
let constraint = 
     NSLayoutConstraint(
          item: myLabel, // [1]
          attribute: NSLayoutConstraint.Attribute.centerX, // [2]
          relatedBy: NSLayoutConstraint.Relation.equal, // [3]
          toItem: myButton, // [4]
          attribute: NSLayoutConstraint.Attribute.centerX, // [5]
          multiplier: 1.0, // [6]
          constant: 0.0 // [7]
     )
```

Comment: Thanks for that, I caught everything except the offset.  What is offset?

Comment: When you want to *set* something somewhere, but the result should be a bit *off* from there. It is **offset**. for example it should originally be on *100*, but *50* different, the result is (100 + 50) and *50* is the offset.